# Unittest test suite

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test suite and I executed the same but my test suite executed a single test script twice. I want to execute the test script only once and the report should be generated for the same.

```
Import HTMLTestRunner

class SmokeTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    print('Running test suite')

    dir = os.getcwd()
    testLoad = unittest.TestLoader()
    print(dir)
    test_classes_to_run = [xyz_test_class]

    suites_list = []
    for test_class in test_classes_to_run:
        suite = testLoad.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        suites_list.append(suite)
    print(suites_list)
    newSuite = unittest.TestSuite(suites_list)
    print(newSuite.countTestCases())
    timestr = time.strftime("_%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")

    resultFile = open(os.path.join(dir, "TestReport"+ timestr + ".html"), "w")
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(stream=resultFile, title='Test Report', description='Tests Execution Report') 

    runner.run(newSuite)
```

It Executed a single test script xyz_test_class two times.

Answer (score 0):

TestCase is a class, which children should define test methods, like `test_foo(self)`. So, put your code into method, like this:

```py
class SmokeTestSuite(TestCase):
    def test_smoke(self):
        '''your code goes here'''
```

Anyway, why would you do not just use auto-discover thing?

Comment: I am new in python automation so just exploring and trying python stuff that why not much info about all features.

Comment: Problem not solved with the above code still facing the same issue.